# Webpack Initialization Fails

Tags: javascript, webpack

I just got into Webpack following an online tutorial.

Whenever I run `npm run dev` the web pack doesn't run and gives me the error: `Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.`

`- configuration.output has an unknown property 'fileName'. These properties are valid:
   object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkFilename?, webassemblyModuleFilename?, globalObject?, crossOriginLoading?, jsonpScriptType?, chunkLoadTimeout?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolNamespace?, filename?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, chunkCallbackName?, library?, libraryTarget?, libraryExport?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine? }
   -> Options affecting the output of the compilation.`output`options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.`

Here are my files:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Forkify Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Sanjay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        fileName: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'
}
```

Comment: I think changing `fileName` to `filename` will solve your problem.

Comment: @IlyasDeckers That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your output object is wrong. ( fileName => filename )

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'
}
```